# How to customize the wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and i'm creating a site using wordpress.

You can see the mock up page here http://www.site2preview.com/veejata/ver1/index.html

And i've changed the index.php as

```
<?php
get_header(); 

//get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
?>

<div class="flt_left"> 
    //dummy welcome text ..
</div>
<div class="flt_left">
    //dummy latest post..
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_advt(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now i want to know how to create a custom page or block and how can i include them in the index.page..

Also i want the user should be able to edit the dummy welcome text from the admin panel..

In general i want to **`how to split the contents in the wordpress`** and **`how to make them editable by admin`** and **`how to include them in the pages`**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should have in your simple index.php file (from wordpress classic theme):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
<?php the_date('','<h2>','</h2>'); ?>    
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
     <h3 class="storytitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
     <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div class="meta"><?php _e("Filed under:"); ?> <?php the_category(',') ?> 
      &#8212; <?php the_tags(__('Tags: '), ', ', ' &#8212; '); ?> 
      <?php the_author() ?> @ 
      <?php the_time() ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit This')); ?></div>    
    <div class="storycontent">
        <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
    </div>    
    <div class="feedback">
      <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
      <?php comments_popup_link(__('Comments (0)'), 
           __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)')); ?>
    </div>    
</div>    
<?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>    
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would suggest you to read this first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: I'm using latest wordpress and the index.php has only get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );       And can you please link any other tutorial to create custom home page

Comment: As I understand this new function `get_template_part` is helpful in creating child themes. Take a look at this article: http://voodoopress.com/2011/02/get_template_part-in-my-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Can we have a page or block for the dummy welcome text in the admin page where he can edit the content so that the home page content changes.. I can include the contents in php file and use like get_advt() but instead of editing php file i want to let my admin edit the content from admin panel much alike for pages in wordpress.. Is that possible if yes then how to create and include them?

Comment: @kvijayhari: If that is prime requirement then I would suggest stick with original index.php that came with default theme. Once you create a post/page from wordpress admin and publish it you will get a URL generated by Wordpress. That post/page is always editable in WYSIWYG wordpress html editor and is automatically wrapped by default theme's index, header, footer, sidebar etc.

Comment: Post will be automatically wrapped by index.php but how the pages will be wrapped up with the default index.php?

Comment: @kvijayhari: By default wordpress chooses your **selected** theme's index.php to wrap the newly created post/page (as long as you are using default template in post editor).

Comment: Thats not working.. is there any properties i need to set while creating pages for the pages to be automatically wrapped up..??

Comment: @kvijayhari: That's really strange. Lets create a new page in Wordpress admin and put some sample text in it. Make sure in right hand `Page Attributes` section of that page `Parent` shows **(no parent)** and `Template` shows **Default Template**. Then publish this page and wordpress will generate and provide you a link of newly created page. Once you open that link, page is wrapped by `page.php` file. I would strong suggest you looking at this diagram to understand which php file is used for what component: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: Also strongly recommended is reading this article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy I use it as bible for my own reference.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your explanation.. I'll check out these